# Extract a range of tables from word document

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

My Word document has 50 tables in it, i need to know how can i extract the table number 20 to table number 30 from the word document.
Currently the code i am using is extracting all tables from the word document.
Also, if possible could we allow the user to input the range when the script is run ?

```
 Option Explicit

Sub ImportWordTables()

    Dim wd As Word.Application
    Dim doc As Word.Document
    Dim tbl As Word.Table
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set wd = New Word.Application
    wd.Visible = True
    
    Set doc = wd.Documents.Open(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\fivetables.docx")
    
    For Each tbl In doc.Tables
    
        tbl.Range.Copy
        Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
        ws.PasteSpecial "HTML"
        ws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.EntireColumn.AutoFit
        
    Next tbl
    
    doc.Close
    wd.Quit
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example:

```
Sub ImportWordTables()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim wdApp As New Word.Application, wdDoc As Word.Document
Dim xlWkSht As Worksheet, i As Long, j As Long, t As Long
With wdApp
  .Visible = False
  Set wdDoc = .Documents.Open(FileName:=ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\fivetables.docx", AddToRecentFiles:=False)
  With wdDoc
    t = .Tables.Count
    i = CLng(InputBox("The document has " & t & " tables." & vbCr & _
        "Table to start at?"))
    If i < 1 Then GoTo ErrExit
    If i > t Then GoTo ErrExit
    j = CLng(InputBox("The document has " & t & " tables." & vbCr & _
        "Table to end at?"))
    If j > t Then j = t
    For t = i To j
      .Tables(t).Range.Copy
      Set xlWkSht = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
      xlWkSht.PasteSpecial "HTML"
      xlWkSht.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.EntireColumn.AutoFit
    Next
ErrExit:
    .Close False
  End With
  .Quit
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Irrespective of the word document that i use , its giving me " the document has 0 tables"

Comment: Extraneous code left over from testing. Revised. Try it now.

Comment: I am getting the following error.  Compile error: User defined type not defined for "Dim xlWkSht As Worksheet"

Comment: added Microsoft Runtime Object as reference. It worked

Comment: Thanks a ton !! out of curiosity is it possible to extract based on page number rather than table count ? Its difficult for end users to check the table count from word document when there are 50 tables.

Comment: Yes, but that would require substantially different code. You should post a new question if that's what you want.

Comment: Sure, created https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72094465/extract-a-range-of-tables-from-word-document-based-on-page-number

Answer (score 0):

The basic answer to your question is to use the `Item`-property of the Tables-Collection to retrieve the specified range of tables

I would split the code into four parts:

- main routine (`importWordTables`)
- sub to get the user input for the table indeces `getTableIndeces`
- sub that checks input for valid data and raises errors if the input isn't correct `checkValidIndexInput`
- sub to import the tables specified by user `importWordTablesFromTo`.
- last but not least I am using a function to get the WordApp - which returns the current instance of word if open otherwise opens word. `getWordApp`

```vb
Public Sub importWordTables()

On Error GoTo err_Import

    Dim wd As Word.Application
    Dim doc As Word.Document
    
    Set wd = getWordApp
    
    'Set doc = wd.Documents.Open(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\fivetables.docx")
        
    Dim iFrom As Long, iTo As Long
    
    getTableIndeces doc, iFrom, iTo
    
    importWordTablesFromTo doc, iFrom, iTo
    
    doc.Close
    
exit_Import:
    If Not doc Is Nothing Then doc.Close
    Exit Sub
    
err_Import:
    MsgBox Err.Description, vbCritical
    Resume exit_Import

End Sub
```

To get and check table indeces:

```vb
Private Sub getTableIndeces(doc As Word.Document, ByRef iFrom As Long, ByRef iTo As Long)

Dim cntTables As Long
cntTables = doc.Tables.Count

Dim varFrom As Variant, varTo As Long

varFrom = InputBox("Index of first table to be imported (no of tables: " & cntTables & ")", "Import tables: first table", 1)
checkValidIndexInput varFrom, cntTables

iFrom = varFrom


varTo = InputBox("Index of last table to be imported (no of tables: " & cntTables & ")", "Import tables: last table", cntTables)
checkValidIndexInput varTo, cntTables, iFrom
iTo = varTo


End Sub

Private Sub checkValidIndexInput(ByVal varIndex As Variant, ByVal cntTables As Long, Optional iFrom As Long)
If Not IsNumeric(varIndex) Then 'not a number
    Err.Raise vbObjectError, , "Please enter a valid number as index."
    
ElseIf varIndex < 0 Or varIndex > cntTables Then  'not within range
    Err.Raise vbObjectError, , "Index of the table has to be between 1 and " & cntTables & "."

ElseIf iFrom > 0 And varIndex < iFrom Then
    Err.Raise vbObjectError, , "Index of last table has to be greater than index of first table (" & iFrom & ")."
End If
End Sub
```

Writing the selected table range to the current workbook:

```vb
Sub importWordTablesFromTo(doc As Word.Document, iFrom As Long, iTo As Long)

    Dim i As Long, tbl As Word.Table, ws As Worksheet
    
    For i = iFrom To iTo   
        Set tbl = doc.Tables.Item(i)     '---> retrieve the specified table
        
        tbl.Range.Copy
        Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
        ws.PasteSpecial "HTML"
        ws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.EntireColumn.AutoFit
        
    Next
       
End Sub
```

To retrieve the current or a new word instance:

```vb
Private Function getWordApp() As Word.Application

Dim WordApp As Word.Application

On Error Resume Next    'in case Word isn't already open
Set WordApp = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
If Err > 0 Or WordApp Is Nothing Then
    Set WordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
End If

WordApp.Visible = True

Set getWordApp = WordApp
End Function
```

Comment: Its giving me an error

Comment: Where do you get the error?